# string specifier ( %d , %f etc...)

Tags: c, specifier

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define Type int

int main()
{
        Type x=3;
        printf("%d",x);
        return 0;

}
```

The code is simple and works fine. My question is, if I change  `#define Type int` to  `#define Type float` so , I have to change `%d` to `%f` as well. Is there any way to have a generic specifier, that would work for all `int`, `float`, `char`, `string` etc... So that, if I change `#define Type int` then I don't have to change the format specifiers within `printf()` function?

Comment: Yes, there is a way.  It is called "Rewritting the printf function."

Comment: `#define TYPE_FMT "d"`, followed by `printf("%" TYPE_FMT, x);`.  For `float`, just change your `#define` to `#define TYPE_FMT "f"`.

Answer (score 5):

This is what I suggest:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define TYPE int
#define TYPE_FORMAT "%d"

int main()
{
    TYPE x=3;
    printf("Value of x is: " TYPE_FORMAT "\n", x);
    return 0;
}
```

There is no way to make `printf()` auto-detect types in C.  In C++, you can use the overloaded `<<` operator, and that *does* figure out the types automatically, but C has nothing like it.

But you can `#define` a format as well as a type, and if you put multiple string literals next to each other the C compiler will auto-merge them into a single string constant.

P.S. Instead of using `#define` for the type, you should probably use `typedef` like so:

```
typedef int TYPE;
```

This means that in the debugger, you can see that your variable `x` is of type `TYPE`, while with the `#define` you would see it as type `int`.

And in a perfect world you would declare the format string like so:

```
static char const * const TYPE_FORMAT = "%d";
```

But we do not live in a perfect world.  If you do the above declaration for `TYPE_FORMAT`, the compiler is probably not smart enough to merge the string in with other string literals.  (I tried it with GCC, and as I expected I got an error message.)  So for the `TYPE_FORMAT` you absolutely should use the #define.

Summary: use the `typedef` for the type but use the `#define` for the format.

Answer (score 2):

With the new C standard C11 you could use type generic expressions like this one

```
#define MYFORMAT(X) \
_Generic(+(X)       \
   int: "%d",       \
   float: "%g",     \
   double: "%g",    \
   ... whatever ... \
)
```

and then use this as

```
printf("the value is " MYFORMAT(x), x);
```

The latest version of the clang compiler implements `_Generic` already, so there is no excuse to not use it anymore.

Comment: "...there is no excuse to not use it anymore" because one compiler has it?  I don't know about you, but I need to write code that compiles under GCC, Microsoft C, and various DSP compilers (ADI, TI, etc.) in addition to Clang.  I'm happy to see this, but I won't be able to use it for quite some time.

Comment: Should have put a smiley there :) BTW gcc already has extensions that can be used to emulate `_Generic`, but with MS your screwed, they don't even support C99.

Comment: "[MS] don't even support C99"  Oh, don't I know it!  Some things you can work around (like `typedef __int32 int32t;`) but some things are just broken.  The one I really miss is designated union initializers.  :-(